# WP Отображение значений назначеной таксономии

Tags: wordpress

Есть создание вот такого произвольного типа записи `companies` Ему назначена произвольная таксономия `company_type`

```
function create_company_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Companies',
        'singular_name' => 'Company',
        'menu_name' => 'Companies',
        'name_admin_bar' => 'Company',
        'add_new' => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Company',
        'new_item' => 'New Company',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Company',
        'view_item' => 'View Company',
        'all_items' => 'All Companies',
        'search_items' => 'Search Companies',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Companies:',
        'not_found' => 'No companies found.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No companies found in Trash.'
    );

    $args = array(
        'label' => __('companies', 'am'),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'author'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'company_type'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'company', // slug
            'with_front' => false,
            'pages' => true
        ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-building', // https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/

    );

    register_post_type('companies', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'create_company_type', 0);

///// Create custom taxonomy  'company_type'

function custom_company_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Types of Companies', 'taxonomy general name', 'am' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Type of Company', 'taxonomy singular name', 'am' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Types of Companies', 'am' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Types of Companies', 'am' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Types of Companies', 'am' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Type of Company', 'am' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Type of Company', 'am' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Type of Company', 'am' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Type of Company Name', 'am' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Types of Companies with commas', 'am' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Types of Companies', 'am' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Types of Companies', 'am' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Types of Companies', 'am' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'company_type', array( 'companies', ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_company_taxonomy', 0 );
```

которую можна задать в админке данному типу записи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function add_company_type_metabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'company_type_metabox',
        'Company Type',
        'display_company_type_metabox',
        'companies',
        'side',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_company_type_metabox');

function display_company_type_metabox($post) {
    $selected = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_company_type', true);
    $terms = get_terms('company_type', 'hide_empty=0');
    echo '<label for="company_type">Select Company Type:</label><br>';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $checked = is_array($selected) && in_array($term->term_id, $selected) ? 'checked' : '';
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="company_type[]" value="' . esc_attr($term->term_id) . '" ' . $checked . '> ' . esc_html($term->name) . '</label><br>';
    }
}

function save_company_type_metabox($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (isset($_POST['company_type'])) {
        $selected = array_map('intval', $_POST['company_type']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_company_type', $selected);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, '_company_type');
    }
}
add_action('save_post_companies', 'save_company_type_metabox');
```

Тут все хорошо. Таксономии задаються и сохраняються. Вопрос - почему на странице всех Компаний они не отображаються как назначеные ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И на странице таксономии тоже не отображаються...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немогу понять, что не так, по [add_meta_box()](https://misha.agency/wordpress/add_meta_box.html)  вроде ж все указываю. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Зачем там метабокс с сохранением в мету? Этот код не имеет отношения к таксономиям.

Comment: При регистрации таксономии, Вам нужно добавить параметр `'show_in_rest' => true,`, таким образом появится стандартный метабокс. Тот метабокс что Вы написали, не имеет отношения к таксономиям и просто сохраняет значение в метаполе и все. Таксономии и их связь с записями, не хранятся как метаданные, для этого существуют отдельные таблицы.

Comment: Спасибо, большое.